# Simplify redirect domain to non-www SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I am using the follow .htaccess code to do the following:

- redirect example.com to https://example.com
- redirect wwww.example.com to https://example.com
- rewrite anything that comes after `/$1` to `index.php?get=$1`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?get=$1 [L]
```

This works fine but can this code still be simplified?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `http->https` rule and `www` removal rule into a single rule and have your .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php?get=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Interesting that this adds an additional line.